# How to implement tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits

Tags: tensorflow, sigmoid

I am currently learning tensorflow, and I have run into an issue  with
`tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y,logits=logits)`. The function description says that both labels and logits must be of the same type. I have the function below that I am using to classify MNIST images. The following are key section of my code

```
X=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(None,n_inputs),name="X")
y=tf.placeholder(tf.int32,shape=(None),name="y")

def neuron_layer(X,W,b,n_neurons,name,activation=None):
    with tf.name_scope(name):
        n_inputs=int(X.get_shape()[1])
        stddev=2/np.sqrt(n_inputs)
        z=tf.matmul(X,W)+b
        if activation=="sigmoid":
            return tf.math.sigmoid(z)
        else:
            return z
with tf.name_scope("dnn"):
    hidden1=neuron_layer(X,W1,b1,n_hidden1,"hidden",activation="sigmoid")
       logits=neuron_layer(hidden1,W2,b2,n_outputs,"outputs",activation="sigmoid")
with tf.name_scope("loss"):
    xentropy=tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y,logits=logits)
loss=tf.reduce_mean(xentropy,name="loss")
```

I get  the error: input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type int32 that does not match type float32 of argument 'x

if I change 
`y=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(None),name="y")`. I get the error
Value passed to parameter 'targets' has DataType float32 not in list of allowed values: int32, int64. Yet logits can only be float32 or float64. Please help me fix the issue. Thanks

Comment: As you are using the MNIST images classification data, you should use `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` as there is only one correct label, for each prediction (check out Multi-Label vs Multi-Label Classification [see link for more info](https://gombru.github.io/2018/05/23/cross_entropy_loss/)). Also your last layer should not have an activation as it is integrated in `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` and `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` for optimization.

Comment: Thanks. This was so helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` is the wrong function. In your case you should use `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` instead (actually, that one yields a deprecation warning, so `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2` is the correct one). Also note, as also mentioned in the comments, that the point of these two functions is that they have a sigmoid (or softmax, respectively) built in, so your model shouldn't have any activation function on the last layer.

Regarding the issue: I just tried it with tensorflow version 1.14.0. There, the issue still occurs if `y` has type `int32`. However, it works smoothly if both, `y` and `labels`, have type `float32`.

It's kind of inconsistent that `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` does not perform this cast itself, while `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` has no issue with `y` being `int32`.